# How to I block bad bots from my site without interfering with real users?

Tags: performance, apache, captcha, bots, robots.txt

I want to keep no-good scrapers (aka. bad bots that by defintition ignores `robots.txt`) that steal content and consume bandwidth off my site.  At the same time, I do not want to interfere with the user experience of legitimate human users, or stop well-behaved bots (such as Googlebot) from indexing the site.

The standard method for dealing with this has already been described here: [Tactics for dealing with misbehaving robots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/tactics-for-dealing-with-misbehaving-robots).  However, the solution presented and upvoted in that thread is *not* what I am looking for.

Some bad bots connect through tor or botnets, which means that their IP address is ephemeral and may well belong to a human being using a compromised computer.

I've therefore been thinking about how to improve the industry standard method by letting the "false positives" (i.e. humans) that has their IP blacklisted get access to my website again. One idea is to stop blocking these IPs outright, and instead asking them to pass a CAPTCHA before being allowed access. While I consider CAPTCHA to be a PITA for legitimate users, vetting suspected bad bots with a CAPTCHA seems to be a better solution than blocking access for these IPs completely. By tracking the session of users that completes the CAPTCHA, I should be able to determine whether they are human (and should have their IP removed from the blacklist), or robots smart enough to solve a CAPTCHA, placing them on an even blacker list.

However, before I go ahead and implement this idea, I want to ask the good people here if they foresee any problems or weaknesses (I am already aware that some CAPTCHAs has been broken - but I think that I shall be able to handle that).

Comment: Stack overflow employs the Captcha method. Did you notice that? No? Then it's not a PITA for a normal user.

Comment: The number 2 answer in that thread is an excellent idea as well. ProjectHoneyPot is the basis for a commercial service (http://www.cloudflare.com/) that addresses the issue through DNS.     RBL's and blacklists like ProjH.. can do wonders.  Bot writers are very sophisticated and can hide their tracks, throttle and change IP's frequently.  You'll never stop them all and a new one pops up everyday.

Comment: @gview those throttling bots don't really need to be blocked, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think blocking these bots is really worth the effort, until such a time as they are interfering with your ability to serve your real visitors.  Making life difficult for your real visitors is a proven way to limit your success.  I would never interrupt viewing with a captcha.  With that said, I was in the Cloudflare beta group and it virtually eliminated bot traffic to the site where I was testing it.

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes, I've most certainly noticed.  With respect to how painful it is: YMMV - I am not conducting a survey about that. I want to hear criticism about the method I propose, and (I hope) suggestions for improving it.

Comment: If you have an infected PC, how is a user filling in a CAPTCHA going to guarantee it's no longer infected?

Comment: @Pekka, the answer is obviously: It will not. However, I don't think the *bot* using that PC as its base will fill in a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @Gisle my thinking was - if a bot is using a machine at the same time as an innocent person, how can you tell apart legitimate use from malicious use? And won't un-blacklisting the IP open the door to the bot to continue causing trouble, eventually leading to blacklisting again etc.? I may be looking at things wrong, though, this is just theory.

Comment: @Pekka, I am not too worried about your first point.  Bots use hijacked PCs to cloak their IP, not to piggyback on CAPTCHA solving.  I agree with your second point - I've no way of knowing whether the person logged on (and being whitelisted) has cleaned his PC.  However, I don't think a cure need to be 100 % to be effective.  But I'll bear it in mind and think about some additional logic identfying patterns that indicate that the human own an infected PC (maybe even pop up a kind and gentle message about the benefits of having a clean PC when someone matching that pattern is shown a CAPTCHA).

Answer (score 1):

The question I believe is whether or not there are foreseeable problems with captcha. Before I dive into that, I also want to address the point of how you plan on catching bots to challenge them with a captcha. TOR and proxy nodes change regularly so that IP list will need to be constantly updated. You can use [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com) for a decent list of proxy addresses as your baseline. You can also find services that update the addresses of all the TOR nodes. But not all bad bots come from those two vectors, so you need find other ways of catching bots. If you add in rate limiting and spam lists then you should get to over 50% of the bad bots. Other tactics really have to be custom built around your site.

Now to talk about problems with Captchas. First, there are services like http://deathbycaptcha.com/. I dont know if I need to elaborate on that one, but it kind of renders your approach useless. Many of the other ways people get around Captcha's are using OCR software. The better the Captcha is at beating OCR, the harder it is going to be on your users. Also, many Captcha systems use client side cookies that someone can solve once and then upload to all their bots. 
Most famous I think is Karl Groves's list of 28 ways to beat Captcha. http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/02/09/list-of-resources-breaking-captcha/

For full disclosure, I am a cofounder of [Distil Networks](http://www.distilnetworks.com), a SaaS solution to block bots. I often pitch our software as a more sophisticated system than simply using captcha and building it yourself so my opinion of the effectivity of your solution is biased.